# Knockout Js computed not working in a model

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I am trying to modify the following knockout js model binding to fit my requirement: http://jsfiddle.net/zrBuL/291/. The modification is as follows:

HTML:

```
<label>Male
   <input type="radio" name="IsMale" value="a" data-bind="checked:IsMale"/>
</label> 
<label>Female
   <input type="radio" name="IsMale" value="b" data-bind="checked:IsMale"/>
</label>
<div data-bind="text: ABC()"/>
```

Javascript:

```
var vm = {
    IsMale: ko.observable(false),
    ABC:ko.purelyComputed({
    read: function(){
            return this.IsMale();
        }
    },this)  
};
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

For framework, I would favor knockout.js 3.0.0.

The problem is it is not displaying anything for the div above where div's text property is bound to ABC().

Hint: If I replace following line in read function:

```
return this.IsMale();
```

with the following line:

```
return "Hi";
```

then it works like a charm.

Is there anything I am missing in calling the property IsMale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing `purelyComputed` to `pureComputed` and upgrading to at least Knockout 3.2.0 you get to another problem.
`this` in an object definition is the global `window` object.

So to get a reference to `vm` instead of `window` you need to switch to a `function` constructor for it:

```
function MyVM() {
    this.IsMale = ko.observable(false);
    this.ABC = ko.pureComputed({
    read: function(){
            return this.IsMale();
        }
    },this);
};
ko.applyBindings(new MyVM());
```

Then [it will work](http://jsfiddle.net/86qxgfck/).

An alternative way of defining this would be:

```
var vm = {
    IsMale: ko.observable(false)
};

vm.ABC = ko.pureComputed({
    read: function(){
        return this.IsMale();
    }
}, vm);
```

Comment: Thanks Sergiu. Is there any way I can achieve the same without using function constructor?

Comment: No, there's no way of obtaining a reference to `this` in an object's definition (`var x = {stuff: function() { this -> window, not x}`).

Comment: But there is a more in-between solution, see my updated answer.

Comment: Sergiu, your updated solution worked! It saved me from switching to function constructor. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies with two things:

1. There is no `purelyComputed`, it is `pureComputed`
2. Also `pureComputed` as introduced within Knockout 3.2.0, so you will need to upgrade to that version in order to use it.

[**Pure computed observables**](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-pure.html)

Comment: hutchonoid, with knockout js 3.2.0, will it work as I need?

Comment: @sangam Sorry, I just got back to a pc. You sorted now?

Comment: yes now got the solution from Sergiu's suggestion. Thank you!